# calculating a shortest path in a table structure that changes in real time

Tags: shortest-path

I have a table that looks like this

[image]

In table NPC - are AI like characters that move from one point to another. Player - a character that is controlled by the user.

In any moment the player character might move to any cell of the table. But NPC has a particular goal cell that they should reach while moving. For example, blue NPC needs to read blue cell.

[image]

Other NPC are also moving. My goal is to write an algorithm that would allow NPC to reach the cell using the shortest path. As far as I understand it is a typical shortest path problem.

My question is - is there some algorithm that particularly optimized to handle such workflows, or any algorithms will suffice - just with recalculating the path after each move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many; you can find a list [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11855/how-do-the-state-of-the-art-pathfinding-algorithms-for-changing-graphs-d-d-l/11866#11866). The most applicable is probably D*-lite.

However, there are not many off-the-shelf implementations for it, so the vast majority of games just recalculate the best path using A*.  There are many visual and technical tricks for recalculating as infrequently as possible without negatively affecting the game, but that's more of a question for [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com).

For NPCs in particular, you may also want to look into pathfinding with many units at once.  Some typical search-terms for this are "swarm pathfinding", "boids", "flocking behaviors", and "collision avoidance pathfinding"

Comment: looking at D* (and LPA*) it seems they both maintain successors and predecessor vertices. but for undirected graph - what they might be? all vertices around?

Comment: @lapots: Yes. Every directed graph algorithm also works on undirected graphs, because you can turn an undirected graph into a directed graph by replacing every edge with two edges, one in each direction _(with both having the same weight)_